# Workaround for "Unknown template argument type 604" when usinig clang python bindings

Tags: python, clang, c++20

I am playing around with python-clang, version 15. I fed it with a concept, and got error

```
ValueError: Unknown template argument kind 604
```

This is the code:

```py
import clang.cindex

def visit_nodes(node, src_file, depth):
    if node.location.file == None or node.location.file.name == src_file:
        for i in range(0, depth):
            print('    ', end = '')
        print('%s %s'%(node.kind, node.spelling))

        for child in node.get_children():
            visit_nodes(child, src_file, depth + 1)

def load_symbols(src_file, compiler_options = None):
    index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
    translation_unit = index.parse(src_file, compiler_options)
    visit_nodes(translation_unit.cursor, src_file, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        exit(1)
    load_symbols(sys.argv[-1], sys.argv[1:-1])
```

Run with

`-std=c++20 <input file>`

I guess this is lack of functionality in python-clang. Can I somehow extract the type 604 manually, or should I wait for the next release to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, I was also using `-std=c++20` in args. When I changed it to `-std=c++17` the error was resolved. I suspect that the version of the clang bindings / clang itself didn't match or installed clang does not support clang fully. Nonetheless the fix is to tweak the version untill it will match and not errors would be raised.

I am not sure how to make it work without downgrading the c++ standard version.